# UITableView can't reach the new row

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I searched around but find nothing. 
When I add a new row to my tableview. I can't scroll down to the last one, but it is in the tableview. 
May be it is a little bit confused. If I scroll down hard I can see that new row, but can't stay at that position. Once I release, I can only see the second last row.

In addition, there is an action when user click one row, that row will become larger. At this point, I can scroll down to the last one.

Can somebody help me out?

New Update:
May be the problem is due to custom cell. If I use default cell, that's not a problem.

Update 1:

Since many people want to see the code, i'll post some. But I don't think that's gonna help.
This is working code. No problem.

```
- (void)addItemToArray {
    num++;
    [items addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Item No. %d", num]];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)delItemToArray {
    num--;
    [items removeLastObject];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}


#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [items count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.textLabel.text = [items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

But If I change UITableViewCell to my custom cell CustomCell. I can't reach new.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.titleLabel.text = [items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Please post a code how you add a new row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you have the options "Scrolling Enabled" and "User Interaction Enabled" to yes in Storyboard and Check the number of rows for section. Maybe you reached the limit of rows.

Good luck!

Comment: The data source is an mutable array. The point is after I click one row, I can reach the end. And I check other working code, there is no difference.

Comment: Hmm... Are you setting an identifier to your custom cell on Storyboard?

Comment: Like what? I didn't see following sry.  "Try initialize you custom cell like this: - scollaco"

Comment: Can you post your method "didSelectRow"?

Comment: There is no "didSelectRow" method. Comment out. No need that method

Comment: Ok... well, maybe if you change the identifier of your Custom cell on the tab attributes on storyboard and on the method "cellForRowAtIndexPath" to some name different of "Cell"? I hope you have luck.

Comment: Actually, I tried and no luck. Or may be you can post a working code and I can compare.

Comment: The only different thing i do is:  cell = [self.MyTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath]; (Notice it's different of [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier])

Comment: Thanks for your help. That is a problem for my posting code. And I also fix my original problem which is due to [reloadData] happens before loading the table view.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this same problem, and the only solution I found was to reload the table view. And please file a [RADAR](https://bugreport.apple.com), as the number of developers that file a report drives how soon Apple will fix it.

Comment: Do you men [tableview reloadData]? I did that.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work, but set your tableView's contentSize to be higher when you add a new row. Tell me how it goes. :)

Answer (score 0):

Check the height of the cells that are returned. It could be that the cell height is incorrect, therefore the whole content size for the tableview is incorrect.